# What properties does Davros's chair have?

Tags: doctor-who

How similar is Davros's chair (including the Dalek Emperor version he used in *Remembrance of the Daleks*) compared with his famous Mark 3 travel machine? In particular is it possible for Davros to self-destruct or to levitate?

Comment: Off the top of my head, The Witch's Familiar showed that it has a shield capable of withstanding Dalek lasers, and Daleks are generally able to blow up other Daleks so that means Davros' chair is a lot stronger, somehow. I'm sure there are other differences though.

Comment: I edited your title to describe your question a bit better. I hope I succeeded?

Comment: ok, thanks, oh still a few ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the number of times Davros has cheated death then a self destruct seems unlikely. Levitation and possibly the capability to perform a temporal shift as demonstrated by Dalek Caan during the battle of Canary Wharf would explain how he keeps coming back.

Answer (score 1):

Davro's chair is primarily for life support and transport.

Davros' chair brought him back to life after being "exterminated" by his own creation, and kept him alive for many years (centuries?) until the Daleks retrieved him in *Destiny of the Daleks*, and was seen to hover briefly in *Revelation of the Daleks*. In "The Witch's Familiar", it had gained a force field capable of absorbing Dalek blasts--a sensible precaution, given his history with the Daleks.

Also in *Destiny of the Daleks*, it had a button programmed to detonate explosives by remote control.

I doubt his chair could self destruct, as its primary purpose is to keep him alive, which it seems to do very well.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking up Davros and happened across the following [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_of_the_Daleks). It seems Davros was able to levitate in Revelation of the Daleks, but "Davros and the Daleks can also levitate some distance above the ground. In the transmitted version, the camera angles chosen didn't make it entirely clear that the Dalek was flying (some fans commenting that it looked more like the Dalek was giant-sized), so the sequence was remade for the DVD release of the story".